# Why is useState not re-rendering the changes for dates?

Tags: reactjs, date, react-hooks

I have a react form where I have to put in a logic if startdate > endate, it should revert the startdate to current date. I am adding the form values in an useState array object.
Initial array object looks like this -

```
num:"12345"
startdate: "06/14/2023"
enddate: "06/01/2023"
```

I have put in a validation check and once it finds that startdate > enddate, it should change the value of startdate to current date.

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({})

  const revertStartDate = (field) => {
    if (field == 'enddate') {
      setForm((prev) => {
        prev.startdate = new Date().toISOString() // using internal day calculator
        return {...prev}
      }
      )
    }
  }
```

The above code changes the form to below :

```
num:"12345"
startdate: "04/19/2023"
enddate: "06/01/2023"
```

But it doesn't reflect the same on the UI. The UI still shows 06/14/2023 for the startdate. I have read other answers that it's not changing the state even though the values are getting changed.

Any suggestion on how to re-render the form for the startdate?

Comment: Don't mutate existing state. Just don't do it. I don't want to say it's for sure the cause of your issue, but mutating existing state in React is like undefined behavior in C: anything can happen. Clone the previous state *before* changing the date.

Comment: How do we clone the state? Like in another useState or just another array? Any example would be very helpful here.

Comment: You're already cloning it that's what `{...prev}` does (at least shallowly) and since it's in your code I assumed you knew what it meant. But currently you're cloning it *after* you mutate the original. Don't do that. Clone first, mutate second. It may not fix your problem, but it will help you avoid other ones.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you also provide code snippet to your `<input>`.

You might want to consider reading the docs:
[Controlling an input with a state variable](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#controlling-an-input-with-a-state-variable)

> A controlled input makes sense if you needed state anyway—for example,
> to re-render your UI on every edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't mutate state directly. If you want to make sure read this [doc](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state#copying-objects-with-the-spread-syntax).

```
    const [form, setForm] = useState({})

  const revertStartDate = (field) => {
    if (field == 'enddate') {
      setForm((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          startdate: new Date().toISOString()
        }
      }
      )
    }
  }
```

In my opinion updating state like that doesn't trigger re-render.

```
     setForm((prev) => {
       prev.startdate = new Date().toISOString() // using internal day calculator
       return {...prev}
     }
```

Do you want update this directly? Use [immer](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state#write-concise-update-logic-with-immer)!